# Error: [ Uncaught TypeError: _fs.readFile is not a function ]の原因が知りたい

Tags: typescript

###### 質問内容

提示コードの上部のインポート文ですが`fs`を読み込んで`fs.readFile()`関数を使いたいのですが
色々なやり方を試しても以下のようなエラーが出るのですがこれなぜなのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

###### 知りたいこと

`fs.readFile()`が見つからない原因が知りたい。

###### 試したこと

1,提示コードのように色々実験
2,`npm install fs` `npm install fs/promises`等をインストール
3,`npm parcel index.html --open` コマンドを使って実行
4,自動補完の候補にも表示されます。
5,上の提示画像のように関数のリファレンスが読み込まれています。

###### 環境

OS: windows10
ライブラリ：node.js,paracel
言語: TypeScript

###### 参考サイト

ファイルを読み込む: https://jsprimer.net/use-case/nodecli/read-file/
fs: https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/typescript/read-text-file-in-typescript/
実行環境構築に参考にしたサイト: https://ics.media/entry/190325/

###### コンソールログ

```
fs [object Object]
Main.ts:9 fs.promises [object Object]
Main.ts:10 fsPromises [object Object]
Main.ts:11 fs.promises.readFile undefined
Main.ts:13 fsNode [object Object]
Main.ts:16 Uncaught TypeError: _fs.readFile is not a function
    at test (Main.ts:16:8)
    at cSHfb../FrameWork (Main.ts:27:1)
    at newRequire (index.21089774.js:71:24)
    at index.21089774.js:122:5
    at index.21089774.js:145:3
```

###### TypeScript.ts

```
import { main } from "./FrameWork";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as fsPromises from "fs.promises";
import * as fsNode from "node:fs";
function test() 
{

    console.log("fs " + fs); 
    console.log("fs.promises " + fs.promises); 
    console.log("fsPromises " + fsPromises); 
    console.log("fs.promises.readFile " + fs.promises.readFile); 

    console.log("fsNode " + fsNode); 


    fs.readFile("asset/shader/BasicColor.vert",'utf-8',(err,data) => {console.log(data);} );
    fsNode.readFile("asset/shader/BasicColor.vert",'utf-8',(err,data) => {console.log(data);} );



    

}



test();




main();
```

Comment: プログラムをどうやって起動していますか？

Comment: `npm parcel index.html --open `コマンドを実行しています

Comment: 自動補填機能でも候補として表示されるので読み込まれているものと思われます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> npm parcel index.html --open コマンドを実行しています

`index.html` から `TypeScript.ts` を呼んでいるということですよね。
基本的に、ブラウザでは `fs` は動きません。それはサーバ側で使うものです。

ですが、[percel には `fs.readFileSync()` をエミュレートする機能がある](https://parceljs.org/features/node-emulation/#inlining-fs.readfilesync)ようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Typescriptとはサーバーで動く言語なのでp5等などローカルで動かしたいプログラムを作る言語ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: Typescriptはブラウザ側でもサーバ側でも利用できます。fs がサーバ側だけの機能ということです。